# How can I bring an image with a transparent background to the front of my tkinter window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

My image "1_T.png" has a transparent background. I want to bring it to the front of my tkinter window.

I first tried inserting the image in a label. This brought the image to the front of the window but the transparent background was lost because labels can't have transparent backgrounds is my understanding.

I then tried using canvas.create_image(). This helped me preserve the transparent background of my image "1_T.png" but i can't work out how to bring it to the front. I tried canvas.tag_raise(). But that didn't work either.

For example, in the code below, i want to bring the image in front of the label.

Is there a way for me to do that?

```
import tkinter as tk

HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 1000

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg='black', height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

mylabel = tk.Label(root, text='testing', bg='#00FFFF')
mylabel.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.1)

myimage = tk.PhotoImage(file='1_T.png')
myimage2 = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=myimage)

canvas.tag_raise(myimage2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `canvas.tag_raise()` only put the image to the top layer within the canvas, not the root window.  Even though you put the image on the top layer of root window by raising the canvas, the label will be blocked by the canvas because the canvas is not transparent.